Intake shutter valve
My mechanic says the problem with my engine is a blocked oil pickup pipe. I see that my manufacturer has a recall on for intake shutter valves. Is the intake shutter valve and the oil pickup pipe the same thing?
Thanks

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question?

Mazda cx5 2.2 litre diesel

The intake shutter valve is not related to the oil pickup tube.
The oil pickup tube is a pipe into the oil pan connected to the oil pump, so that the pump can get oil into the rest of the engine.
The intake shutter valve is a mechanism to shut off air flow to the intake of a diesel engine, in order to turn off the engine in the event of a runaway.
